# How can I use 'watch' in my npm scripts?

Tags: javascript, node.js, npm

I have the following directory structure:

[image]

And my `package.json` looks like this:

```
{
  "name": "personal_site",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My personal website.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "node-sass": "node-sass --output-style compressed --include-path node_modules/bourbon/app/assets/stylesheets/ --include-path node_modules/bourbon-neat/app/assets/stylesheets/ 'src/scss/styles.scss' 'dist/css/bundle.min.css'",
    "html-minifier": "html-minifier --collapse-whitespace --remove-comments --remove-attribute-quotes -o 'dist/index.html' 'src/index.html'",
    "imagemin": "imagemin src/images dist/images",
    "serve": "http-server ./dist"
  },
  "author": "Dean Gibson",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bourbon": "^4.2.6",
    "bourbon-neat": "^1.7.4",
    "normalize-scss": "^4.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "html-minifier": "^1.3.0",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "node-sass": "^3.4.2"
  }
}
```

So firstly, I have to run each of these scripts individually e.g. `npm run node-sass` or `npm run html-minifier` etc. What I'd ideally want is to run `npm serve` which will do the following:

1. run html-minifier
2. run node-sass
3. run run image-min
4. run http-server
5. Lastly, watch everything in my `src` folder and run
   the respective scripts as files change e.g. `node-sass` etc..

How can I best tackle this problem?

Comment: Have you considered using gulp for that task?

Comment: @rmjoia outdated but gulp was abandoned imho (maybe not). The point is, if you can choose independence from a package, then that's better.

Comment: @Minsky agree.. but that response is from Mar 27 2016...

Answer (score 53, accepted):

You can watch your directories using [`nodemon`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/nodemon).

One solution for you is to create three watch scripts, one for each task:

- `watch:node-sass`,
- `watch:html-minifier`, and
- `watch:imagemin`.

Then have a central script `watch` starting the three:

```
{
  "name": "personal_site",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "My personal website.",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1",
    "node-sass": "node-sass --output-style compressed --include-path node_modules/bourbon/app/assets/stylesheets/ --include-path node_modules/bourbon-neat/app/assets/stylesheets/ 'src/scss/styles.scss' 'dist/css/bundle.min.css'",
    "html-minifier": "html-minifier --collapse-whitespace --remove-comments --remove-attribute-quotes -o 'dist/index.html' 'src/index.html'",
    "imagemin": "imagemin src/images dist/images",
    "serve": "http-server ./dist",
    "watch:node-sass": "nodemon -e scss -x \"npm run node-sass\"",
    "watch:html-minifier": "nodemon -e html -x \"npm run html-minifier\"",
    "watch:imagemin": "nodemon --watch src/images -x \"npm run imagemin\"",
    "watch": "npm run watch:node-sass & npm run watch:html-minifier & npm run watch:imagemin"
  },
  "author": "Dean Gibson",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "bourbon": "^4.2.6",
    "bourbon-neat": "^1.7.4",
    "normalize-scss": "^4.0.3"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "html-minifier": "^1.3.0",
    "http-server": "^0.9.0",
    "node-sass": "^3.4.2"
  }
}
```

Read also: [How to Use npm as a Build Tool](https://www.keithcirkel.co.uk/how-to-use-npm-as-a-build-tool/).

Comment: Good. Single quotes can be used to wrap most of those commands (inside the double quotes).

Answer (score 35):

I advise `onchange`, see [this](https://github.com/damonbauer/npm-build-boilerplate) boilerplate.

For example,

```
"watch:css": "onchange 'src/scss/*.scss' -- npm run build:css",
```

or

```
"watch:js": "onchange 'src/js/*.js' -- npm run build:js",
```

No Grunt or Gulp needed!

Comment: Use ", not ' at least in Windows: "watch:html": "onchange \"src/*.html\" \"src/templates/headTemplate.html\" -- npm run htmlTempl". It does not work with single quotes.

Comment: Remember do install onchange: npm install onchange

Comment: This one should be the accepted answer. Simple library, took me 1 minute to do what I was expecting!

Comment: NOTE: onchance does not support running multiple commands. So you can set a BASH script to be run that does all the server killing, restarting, etc.

Comment: I'll elaborate on what @Pithikos means: [onchange](https://www.npmjs.com/package/onchange) blocks the terminal until killed.

Answer (score -4):

The most widely adopted tools for this scripted case is to go with gulp or grunt.  They are tools that you will encounter very often.  You can also find their grunt/gulp libs for your minify/concat/copy/imagemin,  as well as watcher libs so they change as you make changes to code.  Nodemon/forever/pm2  have watch capabilites  to restart your http server as well

Comment: Thanks @Handonam , Though just to clarify, it IS possible to do what I want to do without using grunt or gulp right? It feels that those tools are just unnecessary middle men and would just be overkill for a simple build.