# Any way to have a listener for when you copy things to the clipboard?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, electron

Is it possible to listen for when you copy something somewhere.

And then execute a function or similar, for example when you copy something `console.log()` whatever you just copied...

This would, of course, be done through `NodeJS`.

Hope that makes sense... :/

Comment: are you looking for `fs.watch` or something like the [watch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/watch) package? maybe [these answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36245415/how-can-i-use-watch-in-my-npm-scripts) can help you?

Comment: I was more thinking when you copy text, then it sends the message to node that you copied and what you copied...

Comment: so you are talking about clipboard not file copy? you should have stated clearer in the question..

Comment: Sorry thought I was clear enough :/

Comment: then maybe try looking at the [clipboardy](https://github.com/sindresorhus/clipboardy) package? although it does not provide watch, but depends on your use case, it might be sufficient to check every second and compares

Comment: Saw It already, and I was actually considering doing something like that... It's just if there were better solutions

Comment: i think barely, actually i believe this watching function is too niche to be included in OS level..

Comment: Took me what, 2 minutes to make a simple watcher function so I'll live with it!