# How do I fix this NPM Watch ENOENT "\\run" error?

Tags: node.js, npm, watch, enoent

I have a simplistic build command for my PostCSS for a simple WordPress project:

```
"build": "postcss wp-content/themes/themename/assets/css/main.css -o dist/main.css",
```

This works perfectly! I set up the npm `watch` package in order to watch for changes in the theme's `css/` directory, so that it will automatically run that working `build` command on a file change.

My final scripts looked like this:

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "postcss wp-content/themes/themename/assets/css/main.css -o dist/main.css",
    "watch": "watch 'npm run build' wp-content/themes/themename/assets/css/"
  },
```

However, I get this error when running:

```
[Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, stat 'C:\Users\user\Desktop\Coding Projects\themename\run'] {
  errno: -4058,
  code: 'ENOENT',
  syscall: 'stat',
  path: 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Coding Projects\\themename\\run'
}
```

The `\\run` changes with whatever I put after that 'npm' inside the watch script. For example, changing 'npm run build' in the watch script to just 'npm build' (just to experiment) changes the "path" to: `path: 'C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\Coding Projects\\themename\\build'`

I'm following the format I've seen used in tutorials and in the documentation, but haven't been able to find anyone else having this error.

Help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37515084)

Comment: Thanks so much for your answer, @Xaqron! However, this was one of the other "watch"-esque packages that I tried previously. It doesn't throw errors when I run a command following the template in that answer, but it doesn't actually update anything onchange. I tried saving several different files after putting in `"watch": "onchange 'wp-content/themes/themename/assets/css/*.css' -- npm run build"`, but to no avail.

Comment: According to `...haven't been able to find anyone else having this error...` and assuming it was done correct, then it is time to think of something outside your config. Bad installation of node.js, lack of adequate permission on file system, antivirus conflict, etc.